# Password Reset Route Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have an angular project that hits a url and send an email to a user email.
Everything works fine and it sends the email containing the url - http://127.0.0.1:4200/auth/password-reset/Mg/bkub0k-13a5906257014a89210c1bc3be8ae924/

My issue now is that when i click the link, it redirects to the login page, meanwhile it is supposed to open the reset-password page as seen in the code below.

I have tried with just `{ path: 'auth/password-reset', component: ResetPasswordComponent }` and it works, but with the id and token it doesnt.

My current codebase-

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {
    HttpClientModule,
    HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    HttpClientJsonpModule,
    HttpClient,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule, MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { SupplierListComponent } from './components/supplier-list/supplier-list.component';
import { MapViewComponent } from './components/map-view/map-view.component';
import { TradingDetailComponent } from './components/trading-detail/trading-detail.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { TradingComponent } from './components/trading/trading.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';
import { ProfileHeaderComponent } from './components/profile-header/profile-header.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './components/notifications/notifications.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './components/messages/messages.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/auth.guard';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { TokenInterceptorService } from './service/token-interceptor.service';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ResetDialogComponent } from './components/reset-dialog/reset-dialog.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './components/reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './components/change-password/change-password.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './components/registration/registration.component';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { GoogleMapsModule } from '@angular/google-maps';
import { RoleSwitcherComponent } from './components/role-switcher/role-switcher.component';
import { LanguageSelectorComponent } from './components/language-selector/language-selector.component';
import { SupplierCardComponent } from './components/supplier-card/supplier-card.component';
import { TooltipComponent } from './components/tooltip/tooltip.component';
// import ngx-translate and the http loader
import {
    TranslateLoader,
    TranslateModule,
    TranslatePipe,
} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from './context/user/reducers';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { UserEffects } from './context/user/effects';
import { LineChartComponent } from './line-chart/line-chart.component';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { DoughnutChartComponent } from './doughnut-chart/doughnut-chart.component';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'trading', component: TradingComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent },
    { path: 'auth/password-reset/:id/:token', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' },
    
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        UserComponent,
        ResetPasswordComponent,
        ...
        
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
            multi: true,
        },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        ...
    ],
})
//rose compile errors ?
//@ts-ignore
export class AppModule {}
// required for AOT compilation
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    CanActivate,
    Router,
    RouterStateSnapshot,
    UrlTree,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../service/auth.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private service: AuthService, private route: Router) {}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
        const isLoggedIn = this.service.IsLoggedIn();
        const id = route.params['id'];
        const token = route.params['token'];
        console.log(`id: ${id}, token: ${token}`);
        
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            this.route.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `{ path: 'auth/password-reset/:id/:token', component: ResetPasswordComponent }`?

Comment: are you getting values of `id` and `token` in the `authguard`? Also, can you share the code of `IsLoggedIn()` in `AuthService` as well, because that is the flag which is redirecting you to `login` page.

Comment: @majusebetter that is what i have on my code... and its not working

Comment: @HarshitT no i am not getting the value of id and token, it outputs undefined.

Basically the isLoggedIn() checks if the user has an active access token, which is gotten from the backend API after a user logs in and is stored in local storage

`return localStorage.getItem('token') != null;`

that is the code in the isLoggedIn()

Comment: @Melody Did you install the `AuthGuard` on a parent route?

Comment: @majusebetter nope i didn't